# csplit not obeying backslash r \r as carriage return

Tags: regular-expression, special-characters, whitespace

I have a file with `\r\n` line endings (CRLF carriage return line feed).

This command works:

```
$ csplit --silent --prefix=email-emailbad.txt- \
    --digits=3 emailbad.txt '/^\.^M/'+1 '{*}'
```

This requires that I press <kbd>CTLR</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to insert an actual carriage return character.

I want this to work, so that I'm using only printable characters (for SVN, etc.)

```
$ csplit --silent --prefix=email-emailbad.txt- \
    --digits=3  emailbad.txt '/^\.\r/'+1 '{*}'
```

I've tried with single and double quotes, and without quotes. Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using, `ksh93`, `zsh` or `bash`, you can use the `$'...'` ksh-extension, which does C-style backslash escape interpretation inside the quoted string:

```
csplit --silent --prefix=email-emailbad.txt- --digits=3 \
       emailbad.txt $'/^\.\r/+1' '{*}'
```

Otherwise, you can use `printf` to create the string, in a very similar way:

```
csplit --silent --prefix=email-emailbad.txt- --digits=3 \
       emailbad.txt "$(printf '/^\.\r/+1')" '{*}'
```

Comment: @stephaneChazelas: Thanks. The quotes around the printf are not required, by the way, although they're probably a good idea. (The default value for IFS is `<space><tab><newline>`. I think that's standard; it certainly works in both bash and zsh)

Comment: Why would you invoke the split+glob operator here? To save a couple of keystrokes, and cause that code not to be portable to contexts where $IFS is not the default? (as a note zsh's $IFS also includes the NUL character).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas sorry - I'm not sure to whom you are speaking, and what suggestions you have to improve the code?

Comment: @FelipeAlvarez, the discussion was with rici and about my [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/134046/2) and the need for quotes around `$(...)`.

Comment: I've accepted this answer because it immediately satisfies the problem. A pity that csplit won't obey backslash r `\r`

Comment: @FelipeAlvarez: I agree. I checked the csplit source; it only uses Basic Regular Expressions (using the standard posix regex library) and there is no option to use EREs. A patch would be trivial but I don't know if it would be accepted. But the extra `$` in the command is not very expensive :)